# Should object definitions in sealed classes start with capital or lowercase letter?

Tags: android, kotlin, kotlin-sealed

For example :

```
sealed class Event {
  object ViewClicked : Event()
}
```

Should it be `ViewClicked` or `viewclicked`?
It seems its a variable , so i guess it should be `viewclicked` but the rest of the codebase on the app has capitalized objects. So i wanted to know whats the right approach here?

Also , can anyone confirm if `object` is like a static variable in Java?

Comment: if you give `viewclicked` it will give an error as classname should start with capital letter

Comment: `object` ultimately translates to a class, so it should follow the same principles as any ordinary classes.

Comment: Shalu, you are incorrect. It does not show any error.

Answer (score 4):

`ViewClicked` is not a variable. Declaring `object ViewClicked` we show that we have only [one instance (singleton)](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/tutorials/kotlin-for-py/objects-and-companion-objects.html) of class `ViewClicked`, so it is definition of a class and creation of its instance on one line.

By [Kotlin style guide](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/coding-conventions.html#naming-rules):

> Names of classes and objects start with an upper case letter and use the camel case.

Therefore the correct definition would be:

```
sealed class Event {
    object ViewClicked : Event()
}
```